# How do I proceed from this algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:
[Formatted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRPKX.png)
Find the values of p and q for which the expression $12x^4 + 16x^3 + px^2 + qx - 1$ is divisible by $4x^2 - 1$. Hence, **find the other factors of the expression**.

My problems with this question:
1) I don't understand what the question means by **finding the other factors of the expression**. Would this mean solving for x?

2)I understand that I have to find the values for p and q first, however **I am unsure how to proceed with finding the value for P.**

**I'm stuck at $P = 12x^4 + 16x^3 + x^2 + qx - 1$.**

How do I proceed from the above step? I don't understand how I can find the value for P when there's a Q inside the equation as well.

Comment: 2) if $P(x)$ divides $Q(x)$ (i.e. $Q(x)=P(x)S(x)$) then $Q(x)$ have all the roots of $P(x)$ and maybe some others. Can you plug $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ into the expression? It will yeild a system of linear equations in terms of $p,\,q$ ) 1) It's about finding that $S(x)$

Comment: If $4x^2 - 1$ divides $12x^4 + 16x^3 + px^2 + qx - 1$ then $12x^4 + 16x^3 + px^2 + qx - 1=(4x^2 - 1)(ax^2+bx+c)$. Expand, then find $a,b,c,p,q$.

Comment: Long polynomial division seems easier @Peter

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - maybe so, I don't know. Certainly $a$ and $c$ can be seen immediately, don't know about the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any polynomial that $g(x)$ that divides $p(x)$, we have that $g(a) = 0 \implies p(a) = 0$

Hence, the zeros of $4x^2 -1 = 0$ will also be zeros of the polynomial

Hence, on substituting $x = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ in the original polynomial and setting to zero, you will get the values of $p,q$ from solving the two equations in tow variables

As for the other factors, use polynomial division to get them once $p,q$ have been found

Edit:

Using the property stated above,
$$P(\frac{1}{2}) = 0
\implies 12(0.5)^4 + 16(0.5)^3 + (0.5)^2p + 0.5q - 1 = 0$$

$$P(-0.5) = 0 \implies 12(-0.5)^4 + 16(-0.5)^3 + (-0.5)^2p + (-0.5)q - 1 = 0$$

This gives you two equations in two variables for $p,q$. Solve the system to obtain them, then use polynomial long division to obtain the other factors

Comment: Dhanvi, what does setting to zero mean? As in the terms P and Q being set to zero?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-division-long.html

Comment: Dhanvi, I have calculated for the P(1/2) and P(-0.5) and I got the answer of -7 & -9 in respective order. What should I do with these two numbers?

Comment: So you want to divide the polynomial $12x^4 + 16x^3 - 7x^2 -9x -1 = 0$ by the polynomial $4x^2 - 1$. Do you know polynomial long division?

Comment: Dhanvi, I have found the vlaue of P and Q by doing polynomial long division. Do I just plug these numbers into the original equation and solve for x?